# libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)

Tags: python, pycurl, pyopenssl

My system is macOS 10.13.1
I was try import pycurl is error

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)
```

I tried these two methods

```
sudo pip uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
sudo pip install pycurl
```

or

```
sudo pip uninstall pycurl
sudo pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/ssl-backend-error-when-using-openssl) SO question.

Comment: I tried other answers to the same questions. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: If you're looking for general advice on the subject, I will recommend what I do.  I try very hard not to install anything directly on osx if I don't have to.  Instead I use docker which allows me to describe my runtime environment and dependencies in a reproducible and isolated manner.  I'll guarantee you that if you do it right you'll never see errors like this and things will get a lot simpler to install, for your peers and well as you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still want to know how to solve this problem and I haven't used docker and I don't know how to use it with pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS Catalina (10.5.2) you may have followed all the guidelines and got a similar error:

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
```

This is a result of curl missing openssl, which doesn't come with MacOS now. As described in https://blog.birkhoff.me/switching-to-the-openssl-version-of-curl/

To fix:

```
$ brew upgrade
$ brew uninstall curl
$ brew install curl-openssl
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```