# pycurl macOS Install issue

Tags: macos, installation, pycurl

I need to install pycurl in order to run a python script, but I can't find the way to do it on macOS.

I have already tried brew, update Pip but I always receive this error after did "pip install pycurl"

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.54.0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/private/var/folders/vk/f193293d0pvd2ynlcpnyx9100000gn/T/pip-install-rxidIQ/pycurl/setup.py", line 913, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/private/var/folders/vk/f193293d0pvd2ynlcpnyx9100000gn/T/pip-install-rxidIQ/pycurl/setup.py", line 582, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/private/var/folders/vk/f193293d0pvd2ynlcpnyx9100000gn/T/pip-install-rxidIQ/pycurl/setup.py", line 99, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/private/var/folders/vk/f193293d0pvd2ynlcpnyx9100000gn/T/pip-install-rxidIQ/pycurl/setup.py", line 316, in configure_unix
        specify the SSL backend manually.''')
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Curl is configured to use SSL, but we have not been able to determine which SSL backend it is using. Please see PycURL documentation for how to specify the SSL backend manually.
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/ssl-backend-error-when-using-openssl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL backend error when using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/ssl-backend-error-when-using-openssl)

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of curl support multiple ssl backend and pycurl is not able to decide which one is used during the installation time. This is a known problem (https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/530) in 7.43.0.2. Lots of people say to install curl with openssl support, but on macos is better to use the default SecureTransport and let the system access the keychain instead of using the bundled certificates in openssl.

Try installing 7.43.0.1 to fix your problems.

```
pip install pycurl==7.43.0.1
```

If this doesn't work execute this:

```
brew link curl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"
```

and try again

```
pip install pycurl==7.43.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for PycURL to find the OpenSSL headers on macOS, we need to specify which SSL backend to use and where OpenSSL can be found:

```
pip install --install-option="--with-openssl" --install-option="--openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl" pycurl
```

That OpenSSL path will vary based on your installation.  On Apple Silicon, this should work:

```
pip install --install-option="--with-openssl" --install-option="--openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl" pycurl
```