# SSL uploading error while using Vimeo API

Tags: python, ssl, vimeo

I am trying to use the Python Vimeo API with PyCharm to upload videos and I am getting the error `ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)`.  I have been reading and it seems like a clock mismatch, but I am not sure about how to go about fixing this.  Thank you so much for your thoughts.

I am using MacOS 10.13 with Python 3.7.

The total error I am getting is:  `File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vimeo
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vimeo/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .client import VimeoClient
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vimeo/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .upload import UploadMixin
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tusclient import client
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tusclient/client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tusclient.uploader import Uploader
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tusclient/uploader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tusclient.request import TusRequest
  File "/Users/administrator/PycharmProjects/Vimeo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tusclient/request.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other)`

Comment: Try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/ssl-backend-error-when-using-openssl

Comment: I will do that.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Alex.  If I am using pyCharm, would the process be the same?  Thank you.